# In case of Spring kafka consumer with auto commit false and MANUAL_IMMEDIATE ack, what happens when exception are thrown

Tags: spring-kafka

If SeekToCurrentErrorHandler is not configured in the consumer, what will be the default behavior of the container, if i have my max.poll.records set to 1, and when the message processing fails and i do not acknowledge the message. After reading the documentation, it's not clear if the SeekToCurrentErrorHandler takes over and retries a max of 9 times and then logs the message and commits the offset and goes to the next record. Does this happen if we implement SeekToCurrentErrorHandler or it happens even if we do not implement it. My goal is to not handle processing failures manually, redeliver it indefinitely, and if i can keep an alert on the lag and if lags exceeds a particular value then i manually intervene.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can configure the `SeekToCurrentErrorHandler` with an *infinite* `BackOff`:

```
/**
 * Construct an instance with the default recoverer which simply logs the record after
 * the backOff returns STOP for a topic/partition/offset.
 * @param backOff the {@link BackOff}.
 * @since 2.3
 */
public SeekToCurrentErrorHandler(BackOff backOff) {
```

And then `new FixedBackOff(1000, FixedBackOff.UNLIMITED_ATTEMPTS)`.

Comment: @artem-bilan- if i have not mentioned anything about SeekToCurrentErrorHandler in my consumer code, 

like 

`public void consume(String  msg,Acknowledgment acknowledgment) throws Exception {

   //processing code for msg which throws exception to client. 
       acknowledgment.acknowledge();                                                                                                
}`
what would happen in above case?

Comment: The default error handler will retry 9 times with no back off, then log the failure.